# Doctrine - Empty leftJoin SQL

Tags: mysql, doctrine

I built the following Parts of my Entities :

```
/**
* @var Application_Model_Ticket
* 
* @OneToMany(targetEntity="Application_Model_Ticket",mappedBy="contacts_id")
* @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="contacts_id")
*/
private $tickets;    
public function getTickets() {
    return $this->tickets; 
} 


/**
* @var Application_Model_Contact
*
* @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application_Model_Contact",cascade={"persist"})
* @JoinColumn(name="contacts_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $contact;
public function getContact() {
     return $this->contact; 
}
```

When I now try the following Doctrine Code :

```
$this->oQueryBuilder->select('contact','ticket')
                    ->from('Application_Model_Contact', 'contact')
                    ->leftJoin('contact.tickets', 'ticket')
                    ->orderBy('contact.id', 'DESC');
```

I get a MYSQL-Error.
The following happens :

```
FROM contact c0_ LEFT JOIN  ORDER BY c0_.id DESC
```

It seems that Doctrine doesn't fill in the LEFT JOIN properly. 
Does anybody have an idea, why this happens ?

UPDATE:

```
->leftJoin('contact.tickets', 'ticket', 'WITH','contact.id = ticket.contactsId')
```

Gives me

```
LEFT JOIN  AND (c0_.id = t1_.contacts_id)
```

Comment: What sql query you want to build using `doctrine`?

Comment: SELECT fields_of_contact FROM contact LEFT JOIN ticket ON ticket.contacts_id = contact.id

Answer (score 0):

you miss the `ON` in your query

```
$this->oQueryBuilder
     ->select('contact','ticket')
     ->from('Application_Model_Contact', 'contact')
     ->leftJoin('contact', 'on contact.ticket=Application_Model_Contact.field')
     ->orderBy('contact.id', 'DESC');
```

where `Application_Model_Contact.field` replace it for the match field to apply the `JOIN`

so your query should be like:

```
....FROM contact c0_ LEFT JOIN ON table1.field=table2.field ORDER BY c0_.id DESC
```

Source: http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/69061/

Mysql Join: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: Hi,
thanks for the reply. Tried 
on ticket=Application_Model_Contact.id , as it is the id that connects with the tickets.
Got the following error :
Error: Expected end of string, got 'ticket'

Comment: I edited, your tables are contact and application_model_contact?

Comment: No,
application_model_contact is the entity, the mysqlDB is contact
Without the LeftJOIN I get a proper result of Contact-Models

Comment: so you want to apply a join between one table?, please take a look to the documentation of mysql JOIN

Comment: No, I have one table contact, which entity is Application_Model_contact.
I have antoher table Ticket, which entity is Application_Model_Ticket.

I treid to built the LEFT JOIN in clear MYSQL with no problems, just  Doctrine kills me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->oQueryBuilder->select('contact','ticket')
                    ->from('Application_Model_Contact', 'contact')
                    ->leftJoin('contact.tickets', 'ticket', 'WITH', 'contact.id = ticket.contacts_id')
                    ->orderBy('contact.id', 'DESC');
```

Comment: Hi,
I tried the following :
    
    ->leftJoin('contact.tickets', 'ticket', 'ON','contact.id = ticket.ticket_id').
Gives me :
Error: Expected end of string, got 'ON'

Comment: No it didnt't, got an error :
Error: Expected end of string, got 'ON'

Comment: Message: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 87: Error: Expected end of string, got 'ON'

Comment: Error: Expected end of string, got 'ON'

Comment: What version of Doctrine are you using?